# Is this a typo?

Tags: grammaticality

> This is a wake-up call to the fact that our waste management systems
>   are not ***be*** as tight and advanced as they should be.

Can I take the '***be***' here as a typo? Or does it have its place in the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks pretty much like a typo. The author may already have thought about the end of his sentence while typing, so a duplicate of the final "be" crept into the middle of the sentence. Our brains do this sometimes. ;)